# SPM target that acts like umbrella framework

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager

The idea is simple. I want to create target in SPM, which has some dependancies and can be imported in the end product as a single module.

So for example I have module called "Core", which has 2 dependancies: "utilities" and "extensions". For know to use Core, you should also import "utilities" and "extensions" like this:

```
import Core
import Utilities
import Extensions
```

What I want, is to make it looks like in Cocoapods (specs and subspecs)

```
import Core
```

Package.swift example

```
let package = Package(
    name: "SomeFramework",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v13)],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "Core",
            targets: ["Core"]
        ),
        
        .library(
            name: "Utilities",
            targets: ["Utilities"]
        ),
        
        .library(
            name: "HandyExtensions",
            targets: ["HandyExtensions"]
        ),
    ],
    targets: [
    
    // Core
    
    .target(
        name: "Core",
        dependencies: [
            "HandyExtensions",
            "Utilities"
        ],
        path: "Core",
        exclude: ["Info.plist"]
    ),
    
    // Utilities
    
    .target(
        name: "Utilities",
        path: "Utilities",
        exclude: ["Support files/Info.plist"]
    ),
    
    // HandyExtensions
    
    .target(
        name: "HandyExtensions",
        path: "HandyExtensions",
        exclude: ["Support files/Info.plist"]
    )
 ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I still haven't found a solution to my problem, but here's what I did.

I looked at the approach that Firebase uses. The idea is to split all `Cocoapods` submodules into separate `Cocoapods` frameworks and add them as submodules with dependencies in the main `podspec`. This will solve the problem with one code base for SPM and Cocoapods.

Unfortunately, in the code you still need to use `Core`, `Utilities`, `HandyExtension` separately.